# Flagging column

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables and after joining them based on specific condition I get the below output

```
name   assigned

abc    laptop
def    laptop  
def    Null
ghi    PC
ghi    Laptop
ghi    Null
jkl    Null
mno    pc
pqr    tablet
xyz    Null
xyz    Null
```

I want a new column and flag it as '1' even if any of the assigned value for a given name is not null.

the O/P should look like

```
name   assigned    Flag

abc    laptop      1
def    laptop      1
ghi    PC          1
jkl    Null        0
mno    pc          1
pqr    tablet      1
xyz    mobile      0
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: How come you want mobile for xyz? Except that it looks like a basic GROUP BY query.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. This kind of question is usually easiest to answer if you can provide a sample input, query, and output. The outputs you've shown here are a bit confusing, because they have a different number of rows, but you only talk about adding a column, not filtering / grouping anything.

Answer (score 2):

USE `CASE`. Try, Like:

```
SELECT name, assigned, CASE assigned IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as flag FROM ...
```

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?

Comment: It is unclear if OP wants GROUP BY. In any case I have omitted the END of the Select for this exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - with `coalesce()`

```
SELECT name, max(assigned),coalesce(max(assigned),1,0) as flag
from tablename
group by name
```

Comment: That coalesce is (probably)  invalid. Has non-matching data types for the input arguments. Besides, will never return 0.